# How to search title in HTML using XPath?

Tags: html, xpath, autotest

I am trying to get 'RGF Administrator' text from the html example below. The difficulty is that title can take two values: 'Application Settings' or 'Параметры приложения'. At the same time, html may contain other elements with title = 'Application options'.

Which can i use xPath for it?

```html
<div>
    <button
    title="Application options">
        <span>
            <span>
                <bdi>
                    RGF Administrator
                </bdi>
            </span>
        </span>
    </button>
</div>
```

I use selenium, but I can't determine the xPath for 'RGF Administrator'.

`xpath = "//*[@title='Параметры приложения' or @title='Application options']"`

won't work since at the same time, html may contain other elements with title = 'Application options'.

Comment: if xpath is not unique, then you can use index to find your item after looping through all identified elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this xpath expression on your actual xml and see if it works:

```
//div/button[@title = ('Параметры приложения', 'Application options')]//bdi/text()
```

Comment: alas(

`SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//div/button[@title = ('Параметры приложения', 'Application options')]//bdi/text()' is not a valid XPath expression.`

Comment: @NeverSleeps Try it by changing the predicate to `[@title = 'Параметры приложения' or @title= 'Application options']` .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using selenium, then you need to use the `get_attribute(string)` method. So for example, when you find the elements xpath:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("xpath")
```

and then do

```
element.get_attribute("title")
```

to get `Application options`

Comment: Yes, I use selenium, but I can't determine the xPath for 'RGF Administrator'. xpath = "//*[@title='Параметры приложения' or @title='Application options']" won't work, At the same time, html may contain other elements with title = 'Application options'.

Answer (score 0):

How many bdi containers do you have on the webpage? If there is only 1, you can literally just use

```
//bdi
```

And you don't need any pathing.